# Enabling page load samples for Google Analytics Site Speed

Tags: google-analytics

When I look at Behavior | Site Speed |Overview  in GA I get the message:

"0 of pageviews sent page load sample"

How are these enabled?  Or is this a ga() call you have to make from DOM Ready?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to why GA reports 0 pageviews sent, even when set to 10% there should be sample pageviews being sent - why does this need to be changed to 100 for any data to be sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your sample set higher. I believe the default is only 10%. I'll paste code below once I get it from my BitBucket repo.

Notice the "siteSpeedSsampleRate" property. I set mine to 100% because I'm greedy and want to know about ALL page views. Helps when I don't have more than 100k page views per month...

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;

    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

FYI - this is the part that is needed:

```
{'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What is  the ga('require') call you have?  Also, I have my tracking code in  the header.  It seems, therefore,  that anything sent to GA from there won't tell them  the page load time since the page hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: this section is right before the end body tag on all of my pages (</body>). Also, see here for the require stuff: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en

Comment: Thanks.  One more thing.  The ga(require) doesn't seem to have anything to do with showing page load time so I assume that just setting the sample rate up to 100% and issuing the ga('send', 'pageview') is all that's needed (and issuing it at </body> instead of <head>).  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I updated the answer to show the part that you needed (separate from my entire google analytics section)